# How to list all exported bash functions?

Tags: bash, shell

In bash, we can export a function in the following way:

```
fname(){
  echo "Foo"
}

export -f fname
```

In this case, function `fname` is exported. But how to list this or other exported functions? AFAIK, command `export` or `export -p` can be used for displaying all the exported/included variables but this does not including functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following will list all exported functions by name:

```
declare -x -F
```

If you want also see the function code use:

```
declare -x -f
```

See `help declare` for details.

Comment: It works for "export" but does not work for functions exported by command "source".

Comment: `source` doesn't export anything. It is just *"including"* another source file.

Comment: Then how do I know which functions has been included?

Comment: This is another question - ask for it in a new posting.

Comment: Agree! A new post is added. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`declare` is the command to use.

Here's an example of setting and exporting some functions and listing them all, or just a specific one:

```
$ foo() { echo "Foo"; }
$ export -f foo
$ bar() { echo "Bar"; }
$ export -f bar
$
$ declare -f
bar ()
{
    echo "Bar"
}
declare -fx bar
foo ()
{
    echo "Foo"
}
declare -fx foo
$
$ declare -f foo
foo ()
{
    echo "Foo"
}
$
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of the chosen solution is:

```
declare -fx exported_function_one declare -fx exported_function_two
```

In my case, as I just wanted the name of the functions, I did this:

```
exported_functions=$(declare -x -F | sed 's/declare -fx//')
```

Which outputs:

```
exported_function_one exported_function_two
```

Hope it helped someone :D